# C# propertyGrid miscellaneous questions about properties

Tags: c#, properties, propertygrid

I have several questions about properties displayed in propertyGrid i cant seem to find answers for:

1) What do i do if my property is a class? When multiple objects are edited, straaange things happen (when property is struct or simple type, its okay, but if property is class, it passes same class's reference to all edited members when value is applied, which is obviously awful, and it wont recognise two class with identical members, because they have different reference, etc)

2) How do i resize the custom dropdown Editor i created for a property?

3) Can i somehow differentiate between empty value and no value when multiple objects have different values? Like, so

- if i have selected 2 objects with same "name" property, it would show name: TEXT
- if i have selected 2 objects with "name" = "", it would show name:
- if i have selected 2 objects with different "name", it would show name:

4) How do i show something when value is blank? It has to disappear when user starts editing! For example, i have property "name" and if its blank, it should have <> displayed in property grid, but as soon as user clicks to edit, when cursor appears, the <> should disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good sample how to implement a custom editor for a property grid in the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx

and a great article how to realize a custom dropdown, e.g. a dropdown with checklist controls in it on codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and

If you combine the two articles, you're done ;)

Greetings,

Comment: Thanks, i managed to convert VB to C# from the article and managed to get it going, now i have several misc questions, i think i'll update this topic not to spawn another one...

Comment: Great, that i was able to help you :)